# System of parameters formed by nonzero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring. Can we take a system of parameters that are non zero divisors of $A$?

Comment: Ehm... I know a definition of system of parameters for local rings, which is the general definition?

Comment: sorry... A is a notherian local ring.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not! Take $A=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ with $x^2=xy=0$.

Moreover, every system of parameters consists of zerodivisors iff its maximal ideal is in $Ass(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of zero divisors in a system of paramethers is linked to the primes associated to $(0)$, I think

If the maximal ideal $m$ is associated to 0, then every system of parameters is composed of zero-divisors.

Now, I'm onest: I don't know if your question has a positive answer. I think the best you can obtain is the following result (but i'm not even sure it is right).
I hope it could be usefull for you.

I want to prove that every system of paramethers have the same number of zero divisors.

We can reduce to the case of a system of paramethers $T=\{t_1 \dots t_{d-1}, t_d\}$ where $t_d$ is the only zero divisor. 
 Suppose now  there exist a non zero divisor $s \in A$ such that $S=\{t_1 \dots t_{d-1}, s\}$  is a system of paramethers for A. If $P$ is a prime ideal associated to $(0)$ such that $t_d \in P$, the absurd  comes looking at the ring $A_{P}$.